# Find the "best" item of a list and print the index position of the first instance in python

Tags: python, list

I need to print out the index position of the highest value of a list on its first instance.

What I have at the moment:

```
temperatures = [4.7, 3, 4.8, -1, 4.8, 4]
# set best_index to 0
best_index = 0
# for each position from 1 to length of list:
for position in range(0, len(temperatures)):
    if position > best_index:
        best_index = position           
# print best_position
print(temperatures[best_position])
```

However, with the above code I don't get what I am looking for, as with that example list I'd get the result of 4 and not 2 as it should be.

What am I doing horribly wrong?

Comment: You are not testing the temperatures, only an arbitrary incrementing integer. `position` is just `0`, `1`, `2`, etc. Think about this a little longer; how would you compare the *actual temperatures*? You only need to replace the `if position > best_index:` test here.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate could help you a lot. combined with *max* you could do it in one line.

Comment: @CristiFati: see the duplicate, there are faster and better methods. I don't think the OP is quite ready for `enumerate()` just yet, though. The duplicate is there because that's the canonical answer for the underlying problem.

Comment: Shortest: `temperatures.index(max(temperatures))`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it's been really useful. Apologies for opening a duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a few things wrong.  First, you are checking if the new *index* is larger than the previous *index*, you're not checking the actual values.  Second, you're printing out the actual value at the index rather than the index itself.

Comment: This is rather a comment.